# Create calculated field in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: 2013, error, calculated-column-formula, visual-studio-2015

I need some help creating a calculated field which includes div styles in the formula. I created a list as part of a project in Visual Studio and now I'm creating all the necessary columns including some calculated fields. The formula works if you create a calculated column directly in SharePoint 2013 but the same formula is not working in Visual Studio Community 2015. I was writing the formulas in Scheme.xml.

I'll write an example below:

```
=IF([CustomField]="","","<DIV style=""text-align:left""><DIV style=""font-weight:bold"">Custom Field</DIV>")
```

The errors for the formula above are:

DIV - **Tag was not closed.**

text-align:left - **Missing required whitespace** and **Missing attribute value on attribute 'left'.**

font-weight:bold - **Missing required whitespace** and **Missing attribute value on attribute 'bold'.**

These kind of formulas are working perfectly when you are creating calculated columns directly in SharePoint but not in Visual Studio.
Did someone had similar experience with that. I am new in Visual Studio.

Thanks in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first thing I see is that yes indeed, you are opening two `div`s, and you only have a closing tag for one of them.  So, you could add a second closing tag, but why not just combine them both into one?  It seems like from your formula all you are doing is using the `div`s to apply styles.  You could combine all the styles into one `div`.  Also, what might be tripping things up is the way you are using quotes.  I would try using double quotes to frame the entire markup, and single quotes around the style attribute.

So maybe try something like this:

```
=IF([CustomField]="","","<DIV style='text-align:left;font-weight:bold;'>Custom Field</DIV>")
```

The reason it might be working if you do it through the UI is that I believe SharePoint does some validation and correction on HTML entered that way.

Comment: The formula worked but without the div. The text in the calculated column is neither bold nor left aligned. Its actually somehow aligned to the right.

Comment: What I wanted to say that Visual Studio didn't throw me an error but the div styles for bold and alignment weren't recognized. On the calculated column I only see normal text.